# BIRT Margin Issue in odt format

Tags: birt

I set the bottom margin for the text field:

[image]

and it works well for html format:

[image]

but the same report in odt format doesn't take the margin into account:

[image]

How to fix this problem?

**UPD**

As a workaround, I added an empty text field and after that the report looks the same as in the html-format, but perhaps there is whatever more beautiful way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Like option, u can add text in HTML `<BR>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).